# Where is the descriptor protocol for python functions described in the language reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, descriptor, python-descriptors

I stumbled upon this nice trick to dynamically assign a *bound method* to a class instance in Python:

```
class X: pass
def f(self): pass

x = X()
x.f = f.__get__(x)
```

What I want to know is where this behavior is specified in the reference.  Here's the closest I've found:

[PEP 590](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0590/)

[Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)

I'd like to know if this behavior **is** in fact specified in the language reference somewhere.
  It seems like an important enough use case to be guaranteed by the documentation (i.e. it's not clear if what appears in a *HowTo* demonstrates a guaranteed language feature or makes use of an implementation detail, and I'd like to think that, in principle, all guaranteed functionality can be deduced from the spec without referring to *PEP*s).

Comment: Your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to put `x = X()`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [this bit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__)`:

> `object.__get__(self, instance, owner=None)`
>   Called to get the attribute of the owner class (class attribute access) or of an instance of that class (instance attribute access). The optional owner argument is the owner class.

You're essentially calling `function.__get__`, whose rather simple implementation (in CPython anyway) is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/003708bcf8f2c58d4b65f68318acf164d713e008/Objects/funcobject.c#L621-L630); it basically calls [`PyMethod_New`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/003708bcf8f2c58d4b65f68318acf164d713e008/Objects/classobject.c#L93-L117), which basically just binds a function with a `self`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the CPython implementation.  It kind of makes my point though, that this is part of the implementation but not explicit in the reference (as far as I've found).  What I'd expect to see in the reference is *...This method should return the computed attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception,* **and for function objects that computed value is the function bound to the instance as a method** (or something like that)

Comment: Well, I mean, you can use this for a trick, but how often do you _really_ want to bind a free function into an instance, and _why_?